# How to hide window border of the game?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

When I run GTA 5, there is this border of the window. How could I hide it?

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 8):

This is the option you should be looking for in the menu. Set it to Fullscreen or Windowed (Borderless).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can press alt+enter to put it into fullscreen, or you can turn off TeamViewer (If you have it).

Comment: How is TeamViewer related to the question?

Answer (score 0):

As it has been mentioned above the option to change the screen type is in the graphics options in the pause menu. Please keep in mind that the game will load up in windowed mode if you have launched the game and clicked away from the Socialclub Launcher window, making it lose "Focus".